# SQL error about arrow implementation but no arrow syntax used

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, google-bigquery, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am performing a Query within a Python AI Notebook to import data as a pandas df. I am getting the following error:

```
ArrowNotImplementedError
```

I have seen this error before when I used the following arrow notation to create an array of structs:

```
  ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT < event_name STRING,
    row_number INT64 >(event_name, row_number)
  ) as session_events
```

To fix the prior issue I had, I switched from the arrow syntax to the casting notation and had no further issues.

```
  ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT (
        CAST(event_name AS STRING) AS event_name,
        CAST(row_number AS INT64) AS row_number
    )
```

Now, I am trying to use the same casting syntax to create an array of structs (but access different columns in my database).

```
ARRAY_AGG(
   STRUCT(
    CAST(page_title AS STRING) AS page_title,
    CAST(row_number AS INT64) AS row_number
)
```

But I am stilling getting `ArrowNotImplementedError`, which does not make any sense to me because I am not using any arrows. Ideas?

Comment: ARRAY_AGG is not a mysql command it is postgresql could you check the redms tag

Comment: thank you for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

I think you are hitting an issue with PyArrow version on AI Notebook. The issue was [reported](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/issues/63) a few days back and the fix is being merged. Meanwhile, you can update PyArrow version on the AI Notebook and give it a try.

`pip install -U --extra-index-url \
https://pypi.fury.io/arrow-nightlies/ --pre pyarrow`

Comment: Thanks, this helped!